# How to know if the state in React Query has changed from another component using useEffect?

Tags: reactjs, react-query

Suppose I have 4 files in React JS, which are: 1 external file, 2 pages and 1 component:

1. **Login.js** (1 page)
2. **counter.cache.js** (1 file)
3. **Landing.js**(1 page)
4. **Counter.js** (1 component)

1- In **Login.js**, I have 3 buttons:
1-1. A button to login in using email and password.
1-2. A button to sign in with third party.
1-3. A button to navigate from **Login.js** to **Landing.js**.

Here is the code of **Login.js**:

```
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { queryClient } from "../App";

const Login = () => {
const navigate = useNavigate();
return(
    <div
      style={{
        minHeight: "100vh",
        display: "flex",
        flexDirection: "column",
        justifyContent: "center",
        alignItems: "center",
      }}
    >
        <button
          onClick={() => {
              // Save 0 into query with queryKey: 'counter'

              queryClient.setQueryData(["counter"], {
                  counter: 0,
              });
           }}
        >
        Login with email and password
      </button>

      <button
        style={{ marginTop: "20px" }}
        onClick={() => {
          // Save 0 into query with queryKey: 'counter'

          queryClient.setQueryData(["counter"], {
            counter: 0,
          });
        }}
      >
        Sign in with third party
      </button>

      <button
        style={{ marginTop: "20px" }}
        onClick={() => {
          // Navigate to Landing page
          navigate("/landing");
        }}
      >
        Go to landing page
      </button>

    </div>
);
}

export default Login;
```

2- In **counter.cache.js**, I have only one **'useQuery'** which is **useCounter**:

Here is the code of **counter.cache.js**:

```
// Here I don't need to fetch anything, just to get data from this **useQuery**
export const useCounter = () =>
  useQuery({
    queryKey: ["counter"],
    queryFn: () => null,
  });
```

3- In **Counter.js**, I'm increasing the counter,then, updating the value using **useState hook** and into cache. In addition, to implement **useEffect** on the counter from **useCounter** if it's changing.

Here is the code of **Counter.js**:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useCounter } from "../cache/counter.cache";

const Counter = () => {
  const { data, isLoading } = useCounter();
  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(-1);

  // Put the value of initial counter from cache which is 0
  useEffect(() => {
    if (data && !isLoading) {
      setCounter(data.counter);
    }
  }, [data]);

  // Implement useEffect on the counter from 'cache':
  useEffect(() => {
    if (data && data.counter !== 0) {
      console.log(`Rendering Counter component`);
    }
  }, [data.counter]);

  return (
  <div
      style={{
        width: "200px",
        height: "300px",
        position: "fixed",
        right: "0",
        bottom: "0",
        marginBottom: "30px",
        border: "3px solid black",
      }}
    >
    <h2>{`Counter is ${counter}`}</h2>
       <button
        onClick={() => {
          data.counter += 1;
          setCounter(data.counter);
        }}
       >
        Increase
      </button>

    </div>
  );

}
export default Counter;
```

4- In **Landing.js**, I'm just using the component **Counter.js** and implementing **useEffect** on the counter from **useCounter** if it's changing (the same as implementing **useEffect** on the counter in **Counter.js** component above).

```
import { useCounter } from "../cache/counter.cache";

const Landing = () => {
  const { data, isLoading } = useCounter();
  useEffect(() => {
    if (data && data.counter !== 0) {
      console.log(`Rendering landing page`);
    }
  }, [data.counter]);

  if(data && !isLoading)
     return <Counter/>
}

export default Landing;
```

My problem is **console.log(`Rendering landing page`);** is not being called, while **ONLY** **console.log(`Rendering Counter component`);** is being called.

So, as conclusion, the useEffect is being called only in **Counter.js** component, but not in **Landing.js** page.

Note that I'm using the following react-query and react-query dev tools version:

```
"@tanstack/react-query": "^4.29.12",
"@tanstack/react-query-devtools": "^4.29.12",
```

What I have tried **(but in different scenario)**, I have implemented the following:

In the **Counter.js** component:

```
useEffect(()=>{
    const event = new CustomEvent("new_event", { detail: SomeDataHere });
    window.dispatchEvent(event);
},[counter])
```

In the **Landing.js** page:

```
useEffect(()=>{

    const handleNewData = (data) => {
      console.log("Rendering Landing component");
    }

    window.addEventListener("new_event", handleNewData);
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("new_event", handleNewData);
    };
  }, []);
```

**Small hint**: in the dev tools, there is a number '2' beside the query key **'counter'**, and that's because I have used the useCounter inside **Landing.js** and inside **Counter.js** component that is inside **Landing.js** page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example, you do this:

```
data.counter += 1;
```

That's not allowed.  Data in the React Query cache is immutable.  When you directly modify it like that, React Query doesn't know about the changes you made, so it can't tell other components that things have been updated (which explains why one of the console.logs isn't happening).  In fact, that doesn't tell *either* component to re-render -- the only reason the re-render happens is because you also have the

```
setCounter(data.counter);
```

(which you shouldn't have because you're duplicating the state between React Query and vanilla React state, and any time you duplicate state, you're asking for problems -- that's why caching is one of the famously hard problems in computer science).

Comment: Mainly, the problem was that I was modifying the data inside react query directly. As you said, the react query doesn't know about these changes. Hence, the other components will never get notified about these changes as well. I had to modify it using the **queryClient** by copying the variables I need to change.

Answer (score 1):

You should not be storing the resulting data in local state in your `Counter.js` file. Instead you should be deriving the state, and updating your queryCache. e.g.

```
const Counter = () => {
  const { data, isLoading } = useCounter();
  const queryClient = useQueryClient();
  const setCounter = useCallback(
    v => queryClient.setQueryData(['counter'], { counter: v }), 
    [queryClient]
  );

  // Implement useEffect on the counter from 'cache':
  useEffect(() => {
    if (data && data.counter !== 0) {
      console.log(`Rendering Counter component`);
    }
  }, [data.counter]);

  return (
  <div>
    <h2>{`Counter is ${counter}`}</h2>
       <button
        onClick={() => {
          setCounter(data.counter + 1);
        }}
       >
        Increase
      </button>

    </div>
  );

}
export default Counter;
```

That said, it's very unsual to use react-query for state that is not stored server side. Usually for a global state/store (like what you're demonstrating) you'd use one of the various global state solutions like Redux, Zustand, or Jotai.

Comment: It might be better to create a minimum reproducible example that uses some async state, but either way the solution will be something like the above unless the operation you're trying to perform is a mutation and not a query.

Comment: Solved. Thank you. I didn't have to change data directly in the react query cache.